# Frequency Distribution by Day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have records of No. of calls coming to a call center. When a call comes into a call center a ticket is open.

So, let's say ticket 1 (T1) is open on 8/1/19 and it stays open till 8/5/19. So, if a person ran a query everyday then on 8/1 it will show 1 ticket open...same think on day 2 till day 5....I want to get records by day to see how many tickets were open for each day.....

In short, Frequency Distribution by Day.

```
Ticket     Open_date       Close_date   
    T1     8/1/2019      8/5/2019   
    T2     8/1/2019      8/6/2019
```

Result:

Result

```
Date        # Tickets_Open
8/1/2019        2
8/2/2019        2
8/3/2019        2
8/4/2019        2
8/5/2019        2
8/6/2019        1
8/7/2019        0
8/8/2019        0
8/9/2019        0
8/10/2019       0
```

Comment: For a handful of dates, Tim's answer is probably the best approach.  If you are trying to do this for a long period of time over a large set of data, there are more efficient approaches.  I would recommend accepting an answer here and asking another question if this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

We can handle your requirement via the use of a *calendar* table, which stores all dates covering the full range in your data set.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2019-08-01' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-04' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-05' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-06' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-07' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-08' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-09' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-08-10'
)

SELECT
    d.dt,
    COUNT(t.Open_date) AS num_tickets_open
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN tickets t
    ON d.dt BETWEEN t.Open_date AND t.Close_date
GROUP BY
    d.dt;
```

Note that in practice if you expect to have this reporting requirement in the long term, you might want to replace the `dates` CTE above with a bona-fide table of dates.

Answer (score 0):

This solution generates the list of dates from the tickets table using CTE recursion and calculates the count:

```
WITH Tickets(Ticket, Open_date, Close_date) AS
( 
SELECT "T1", "8/1/2019", "8/5/2019"
UNION ALL
SELECT "T2", "8/1/2019", "8/6/2019"
),
Ticket_dates(Ticket, Dates) as
(
SELECT t1.Ticket, CONVERT(DATETIME, t1.Open_date)
FROM Tickets t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.Ticket, DATEADD(dd, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, t1.Dates))
FROM Ticket_dates t1
inner join Tickets t2 on t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket
where DATEADD(dd, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, t1.Dates)) <= CONVERT(DATETIME, t2.Close_date)
)
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, Dates, 1),  count(*)
FROM Ticket_dates
GROUP by Dates
ORDER by Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

A "general purpose" trick is to generate a series of numbers, which can be done using CTE's but there are many alternatives, and from that create the needed range of dates. Once that exists then you can left join your ticket data to this and then count by date.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Ticket     VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Open_date  DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Close_date DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Ticket,Open_date,Close_date) VALUES ('T1','8/1/2019','8/5/2019');
INSERT INTO mytable(Ticket,Open_date,Close_date) VALUES ('T2','8/1/2019','8/6/2019');
```

Also note I am using a `cross apply` in this example to "attach" the min and max dates of your tickets to each numbered row. You would need to include your own logic on what data to select here.

```
;WITH
  cteDigits AS (
      SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
      )
, cteTally AS (
      SELECT 
              [1s].digit 
            + [10s].digit * 10
            + [100s].digit * 100  /* add more like this as needed */
            AS num
      FROM cteDigits [1s]
      CROSS JOIN cteDigits [10s]
      CROSS JOIN cteDigits [100s] /* add more like this as needed */
      )
select 
      n.num + 1 rownum
    , dateadd(day,n.num,ca.min_date) as on_date
    , count(t.Ticket) as tickets_open
from cteTally n
cross apply (select min(Open_date), max(Close_date) from mytable) ca (min_date, max_date)
left join mytable t on dateadd(day,n.num,ca.min_date) between t.Open_date and t.Close_date
where dateadd(day,n.num,ca.min_date) <= ca.max_date
group by
      n.num + 1
    , dateadd(day,n.num,ca.min_date)
order by 
      rownum
;
```

result:

```
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
| rownum |       on_date       | tickets_open |
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
|      1 | 01.08.2019 00:00:00 |            2 |
|      2 | 02.08.2019 00:00:00 |            2 |
|      3 | 03.08.2019 00:00:00 |            2 |
|      4 | 04.08.2019 00:00:00 |            2 |
|      5 | 05.08.2019 00:00:00 |            2 |
|      6 | 06.08.2019 00:00:00 |            1 |
+--------+---------------------+--------------+
```